# How do I delete a mark in current line?

Tags: mark

Lets say I jump to mark with `]'` and I want to remove it, how can I do it without typing `:delmarks a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete all `a-z` marks on the current line using this function:

```
function! Delmarks()
    let l:m = join(filter(
       \ map(range(char2nr('a'), char2nr('z')), 'nr2char(v:val)'),
       \ 'line("''".v:val) == line(".")'))
    if !empty(l:m)
        exe 'delmarks' l:m
    endif
endfunction
```

and with a map

```
nnoremap <silent> dm :<c-u>call Delmarks()<cr>
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to swim against the stream on this one.

> Just don't worry about it.

Marks are pretty ephemeral and there are bunch of marks Vim automatically maintains like `'[`, `''`, and `'.` Humans are typically very bad at bookkeeping so we typically use only a few registers and a few marks. I personally only use a few `a-z` marks (typically `'m`) and often only in few immediate contexts e.g. macros or jumping between a few spots. Your workflow maybe different, but I see no reason to "clean up" the marks.

Now to answer your question:

```
nnoremap dm :execute 'delmarks '.nr2char(getchar())<cr>
```

Now you can do `dma` to delete mark `'a`.

Or to delete all marks on the current line:

```
command! Delmarks silent execute 'delmarks '.join(map(filter(filter(map(split(execute('marks'),"\n"),'split(v:val)'), 'v:val[1]==line(".")&&v:val[0]!~#"[A-Z]"'), 'v:val[1]==line(".")&&v:val[0]!~#"[A-Z]"'), 'v:val[0]'))
```

Just map this to a key to so you don't have to type out `:Delmarks`.

Comment: I work with large source files and quite often need to move bookmark few lines up or down. Since @Mass posted similar answer first I will accept his. Thank you for your opinion.

Answer (score 3):

To delete a mark you can use `:delmark` it can be shortened to `:delm`. 
If you really want something shorter you can map a function which asks for an input but it's not really a common practice to have a map which takes a parameter or ask for an input.

```
function! MarkDelete()
    call inputsave()
    let l:mark = input("Mark to del: ")
    call inputrestore()
    execute 'delmark '.l:mark
endfunction
```

Now just map it:

```
nnoremap <F2> call MarkDelete()<CR>
```